# Adding string to an attribute that is generated dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I need to add a string to a specific part of a dynamically generated href depending on screen size. This is what I got

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             var strSC;
             $("[href*='sc=']").each(function () {
                 strSC = $(this).attr("href");
                 if ($(window).width() < 767) {
                     $(this).attr("href", strSC + "m");
                 } else if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
                     $(this).attr("href", strSC + "t");
                 } else {
                     $(this).attr("href", strSC + "c");
                 }
             });
         });
```

I want to put the "m", "t" and "c" at the end of "sc=" query string that is dynamically generated in asp. So for example if the width of the window is less than 767 I want the href to change to `href="www.mysite.com/index.asp?t=undefined&sc=1234567m&f=32`

The problem is I won't know exactly what sc will equal. If any of that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex matching `&sc= any number` should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[href*='sc=']").attr('href', function(_, href) {
        var w    = $(window).width();
        var char = w < 767 ? 'm' : (w <= 992 ? 't' : 'c');

        return href.replace(/(\&sc\=\d+)/, '$1'+char)
    });
});
```

jQuery's `attr` accepts a callback directly, so you don't have to use `each`, it iterates internally anyway.

Inside the callback, the first argument is the index, we don't need that and a common way to show that is just to use `_`, the current value of the attribute is the second argument, named `href` in the function above (could be named anything really).

Then we get the window width, and use it in a ternary, which is just a fancy if/else.

Finally we use a regex that looks for the string `&sc=` followed by any number of digits, and we capture that and pass it to the replacement as `$1` and add the character we got from checking the window width etc. and just return it to jQuery's `attr` and it gets set for each element

Comment: That is amazing. That worked like a charm. If you have the time/desire could you explain to me how this works? PS I will mark as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: If I could give you a thousand upvotes or whatever it's called on this site (newbie here) I would. Thanks a bundle!